# Create URL with a inherited block variable as argument in Django

Tags: django, inheritance, django-templates

I'm trying to create an URL in a Django (1.9) template which parses an inherited block variable as argument. So

```
href="{% url 'overview:detail' '{% block test_id %}{% endblock %}' %}"
```

With the test_id inherited from a child template like:

```
{% extends 'overview/base.html' %}
{% block test_id %}{{test.id}}{% endblock %}
```

When I try to execute this it gives the following error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /testviewer/
>
> Could not parse the remainder: ''{%' from ''{%'

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to, but I assume you just want a detail page for the test object so what you can do is define the `get_absolute_url` method for the `test` instance

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('overview:detail', args=[self.pk])
```

Then in your template you just need `{{ test.get_absolute_url }}`